# Where is the technical documentation (sdk,api) for QuickBooks Enterprise?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am looking to find out more about what's actually supported in QuickBooks enterprise. If this is online, great!

Comment: See your other, similar question for additional details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922204/are-the-apis-listed-in-api-explorer-compatible-with-quickbooks-enterprise/18923020#18923020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get details on our developer docs- here:https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/0080_quickbooks_web_connector

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0260_pos/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads