# Are the APIs listed in API Explorer compatible with QuickBooks enterprise?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

The title says it all, I am looking at this reference: https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData#

but it doesn't make any notes on the compatibility between different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular API you linked to is *not in any way related to ANY version of QuickBooks*. It's the AggCat APIs, which are geared towards pulling financial information from banks (e.g. Wells Fargo, Bank of America, etc.).

**If you're trying to integrate with QuickBooks accounting software:**

If you're a **SaaS application** (e.g. you are building an app to allow many people to connect their QuickBooks to your app) then this is where you need to look:

- https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiName=V2QBD
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2

If you're building a **custom/one-off/in-house integration**, then you need to look at the QuickBooks SDK:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

Regardless of whether you're using IPP (SaaS) or the SDK (non-SaaS) **QuickBooks Enterprise is the same thing as QuickBooks Pro and Premier - all version of QuickBooks for Windows share the same APIs. The APIs are the same for all of them.**

Answer (score 2):

Correct ApiExplorer Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0500_supported_objects

Thanks